Trouble with Matching Tie Points Correctly in Image Fusion Using ORB and BFMatcher in OpenCV
Description:
Hello, I'm working on a project to fuse two different types of images (RGB and LWIR) using OpenCV. The goal is to find tie points between these paired images using feature detection and matching. However, the tie points identified by the ORB detector and BFMatcher are not aligning as expected. I am running the code in Google Colab.
Despite following the standard approach for feature detection and matching, the resulting tie points do not align the images properly. I've verified that the images are loaded correctly and that keypoints and descriptors are being found. However, the incorrect tie points is resulting in inaccurate alignment.
Here is the code.
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_tie_points(img1, img2):
    detector = cv2.ORB_create()
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
    num_matches = min(len(matches), 5)
    top_matches = matches[:num_matches]
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, top_matches, None)
    cv2.imwrite("matches_top.jpg", imMatches)
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, None)
    cv2.imwrite("matches_all.jpg", imMatches)
    tie_points = [(keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt, keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt) for match in top_matches]
    return tie_points

img1 = cv2.imread('RGB_mine.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('lwir_mine.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
tie_points = find_tie_points(img1, img2)
for i, (pt1, pt2) in enumerate(tie_points):
    print(f"Tie Point {i+1}: Image 1 - {pt1}, Image 2 - {pt2}")


After running the code I receive the following tie points and images.
Tie Point 1: Image 1 - (480.1463623046875, 447.8977355957031), Image 2 - (261.2736511230469, 276.2035827636719)
Tie Point 2: Image 1 - (694.241455078125, 654.4283447265625), Image 2 - (193.20001220703125, 691.2000122070312)
Tie Point 3: Image 1 - (997.3189086914062, 561.3651123046875), Image 2 - (644.0, 450.0)
Tie Point 4: Image 1 - (193.0, 370.0), Image 2 - (676.0, 834.0)
Tie Point 5: Image 1 - (191.80801391601562, 371.5200500488281), Image 2 - (650.0, 876.0)

Here are both of the images that I am trying to fuse.
RGB Image
LWIR Image
And here are the incorrect tie points that my code is generating.
All Matches
Top Matches
This is what I have tried so far.

Adjusting the number of top matches to consider.
Changing feature detectors from ORB to other methods like SIFT (not shown in the code above).
Tweaking the parameters for the ORB detector.

Can anyone suggest why the tie points might not be aligning correctly or how to improve the accuracy of the matches? Any tips on preprocessing steps or parameter adjustments for the feature detector and matcher would be greatly appreciated.

why should feature descriptors for the same point in both images come close to being similar? the pictures look entirely different.
